# Data is not getting written in sorted format on target oracle table through SPARK

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a table in hive with below schema
emp_id:int
emp_name:string

I have created data frame from above hive table

```
df = sql_context.sql('SELECT * FROM employee ORDER by emp_id')
df.show()
```

After above code is run I see that data is sorted properly on emp_id

I am trying to write the data to Oracle table through below code

```
df.write.jdbc(url=url, table='target_table', properties=properties,  mode="overwrite")
```

As per my understanding, This is happening because of multiple executor processes running at the same time on every data partitions and sorting applied through query is been applied on specific partition and when multiple processes writing data to Oracle at the same time the result table ordering is distorted

I further tried to repartition the data to just one partition(Which is not ideal solution) and post writing the data to oracle the sorting worked properly

Is there any way to write sorted data to RDBMS from SPARK

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR** When working with relational systems you should never depend on the insert order. Spark is not really relevant here.

Relational databases, including Oracle, don't guarantee any intrinsic order of the stored data. Exact order of stored records is a detail of implementation, and can change during lifetime of the data.

The sole exception in Oracle are [Index Organized Tables](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/tables012.htm#ADMIN01506) where:

> data for an index-organized table is stored in a B-tree index structure in a primary key sorted manner.

This of course requires a primary key which can reliably determine order.